# How to render Values of an Array nested inside an Object in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am working on an assignment for a todo list app that has an array of "todos" nested inside a "projects". I am also learning about and using modules to break up the code. The projectsArray is stored in projects.js, whereas the other code for rendering to the DOM is stored in dom.js.

```
projectsArray = [
    {
        title: 'Client Presentation',
        todos: [
            {
                title: 'Project Proposal',
                date: '2023-11-15',
                important: true,
                completed: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Presentation Draft',
                date: '2023-11-21',
                important: false,
                completed: false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'Shareholders Meeting',
        todos: [
            {
                title: 'Quarterly Reports',
                date: '2023-11-18',
                important: false,
                completed: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Projected Future Earnings',
                date: '2023-11-22',
                important: false,
                completed: false
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

On page load, the list of projects is rendered to the sidebar and I added an event listener so when clicked each project link will run a function to render its list of todos to the main page:

```
// RENDER PROJECTS IN SIDEBAR
function renderProjectsSidebar() {
    
  sidebarProjects.innerText = '';

  projects.projectsArray.forEach((project, index) => {

      // Create list item for each project
      const projectItems = createHtmlElement('li', null, ['header-project-items', '|', 'no-bullets', 'flex', 'gap-sm', 'align-items-center'], 'data-index', index, null, headerProjects);

      const projectTitle = createHtmlElement('p', null, ['header-project-title'], null, null, project.title, projectItems);

      // EVENT: Render project to page
      projectItems.addEventListener('click', () => {
          renderProjectsPage(project, index);
      })
  });
};
```

This is the point where I am stuck. I want only the todos for the project that I clicked on to display. For example, if I click on "Client Presentation" I want it to render ONLY the two todos in its nested todos array. I have the first part working where I can render the title of the project and some buttons to edit and delete the project along with a button to toggle open a modal form to add todos to the project:

```
// RENDER PROJECTS TO PAGE
function renderProjectsPage(project, index) {
  const mainContainer = document.querySelector('#mainContainer');
  mainContainer.setAttribute('data-index', index);
  clearMainContainer()

  const todoHeaderContainer = createHtmlElement('div', null, ['todo-header-container'], null, null, null, mainContainer);

  const todoHeaderTitle = createHtmlElement('h2', null, ['todo-header__title', '|', 'title--sm', 'flex', 'justify-content-between'], null, null, project.title, todoHeaderContainer);

  const todoHeaderBtns = createHtmlElement('div', null, ['todo-header__btn-container', 'flex', 'gap-sm', 'align-items-center'], null, null, null, todoHeaderContainer);

  // Create add todo button
  const addTodoBtn = createHtmlElement('i', 'addTodoBtn', ['btn--add', '|', 'fa-solid', 'fa-circle-plus'], 'data-action', 'edit', null, todoHeaderBtns);

  addTodoBtn.addEventListener('click', () => todoModal.showModal());

  // Create edit button for project
  const projEditBtn = createHtmlElement('i', null, ['btn--edit', '|', 'fas', 'fa-edit'], 'data-action', 'edit', null, todoHeaderBtns);

  // Create delete button for project
  const projDeleteBtn = createHtmlElement('i', null, ['btn--delete', '|', 'fa-solid', 'fa-trash'], 'data-action', 'delete', null, todoHeaderBtns);

  // EVENT: Delete project
  projDeleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => projects.deleteProject())

  // Create container for todos
  const todoContainer = createHtmlElement('div', 'todoContainer', ['todo-container'], null, null, null, mainContainer)

  renderTodos();
};
```

To test that I am able to at least access and render the "todos", I did a forEach loop inside of a forEach loop. This of course shows the todos for EVERY project. I am unclear on how to get only the todos for the current project.

I created a variable called currentProject which stores the index # of the project. My thought was that I would use the index number combined with filter somehow, but I am lost on that step.

```
function renderTodos() {

  const currentProject = document.querySelector('#mainContainer').getAttribute('data-index');
  const todoContainer = document.querySelector('#todoContainer'); 

  const filteredTodos = projects.projectsArray.filter((currentProject) => {
  currentProject.todos.forEach((todos, index) => {

      const todoItems = createHtmlElement('li', null, ['todo-item'], 'data-index', index, null, todoContainer);

      const todoTitle = createHtmlElement('h3', null, ['todo-item__title'], 'data-action', 'check', todos.title, todoContainer);
  })
})
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but `projectsArray` is an array, but you seem to be calling it like a function? `projects.projectsArray((project) => {` Or should there be a `.map()` or `.forEach()` in there somewhere?

Comment: You are right. There was a .forEach() there. I took it out when trying filter() and forgot to put it back when posting. Doh! This is the section I am having trouble figuring out. How to "filter" (not sure if that is the correct term) only the todos for a given project.

Comment: Why didn't `.filter()` work? What about `.filter().forEach()`?

Comment: It "worked" but gave me the same results as 'forEach()'. I think because I don't understand what to filter by. I tried to filter the project by 'currentProject' which equals the index number of the project, but still got todos for ALL projects.

I updated the "what I tried section" above to show this.

Comment: The `currentProject` has the index of the project by getting `data-index` attribute. So, the selected project should be `projects.projectsArray[currentProject]`. And the selected todos are `projects.projectsArray[currentProject].todos`. If you loop the `projects.projectsArray[currentProject].todos.foreach`, then it should loop the selected todos only. You can console the currentProject variable, it has the index value of the selected item in projectsArray

Comment: Thank you @OnurDoğan. I was stuck on that for a couple of days. I knew that I would need the index# of an individual project so I created the variable 'currentProject' to store it. I just couldn't figure out the syntax/logic in the last step.

Comment: As a suggestion, I think, storing `title` field instead of the `index` would be better since the indexes could be updated after sorting or another process if you would add them in the future. The title field will be special so it would be better to store and check it while finding. I hope you handled it then if you are still stuck, then I can try to help